# Parenting objects in bge makes them apparently changes normals?

Tags: game-engine, normals, parent

I'm making a tank game in the blender game engine and the barrel of the tank looks fine until I parent it to the swivelling part, which seems to change the normals, which means I can see through the visible faces to the faces behind it.

---

This is the tank without the gun being parented:

[image: no parent]

As you can see - the gun looks okay, now this is the tank when the gun is parented.

[image]

Why does this happen? Surely parenting an object shouldn't affect it's normals.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that when I parent the gun to the turning part, the turning part has different shadows

Comment: are there any keyframes on the gun , swivel part or barrel?

Comment: It might be you apply a negative scale (on one or three axis) e.g. via the parent.

Comment: Unfortunately you posted an image of the blender preview and one of the game engine render. This is not really a before/after combination.

Comment: @Monster ok - but in the game engine before I parent it, it looks fine

Comment: I would need a demo file to see what happens